# Ноутбук вместо перехода в спящий режим начал выключаться

Tags: windows

Недавно возникла проблема, связанная с тем, что ноутбук (а именно `HP Pavilion Laptop Model-15cw0025ur`) перестал переходить в спящий режим. Система - `Windows 10`

**Суть проблемы:** при нажатии кнопки выключения ноута (одиночное касание), через переход в спящий режим с помощью винды, через закрытие крышки ноута, мой ноутбук выключает экран и кнопка включения продолжает гореть. Это длится минуты 3-5, а после этого он просто выключается и все: то есть при последующем нажатии кнопки включения происходит обычная загрузка системы.

**Способы решения, которые я попытался предпринять:** обновил все драйвера, пытался настроить способы электропитания, перезагружал компьютер.

**После чего начала возникать проблема:**

1. я включил Bluetooth и подключился к своим беспроводным наушникам.
2. После того, как я поставил пароль при входе в систему (пароль, который нужно вводить, например, при нажатии `Win+L`)